# Redirect all urls under specific url to another page

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

I'm developing a multiplatform app (Android+iOS) and I need my app to handle urls for user invites. The urls that my app listens to is in the form of:

http://www.example.com/user/username

Where the "username" is replaced by the actual username. This page does not exist on my webserver, it's only there so my app can get the username and perform an action based on that. What I whant to do is when a user goes to a url of the type "http://www.example.com/user/*" i want my webserver to redirect to my "get the app" page which is at "http:// www.example.com/get_app.php".

How can I achieve this wildcard redirection on my server? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding the following lines  to your .htaccess-File should do the trick:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^user/([^/]*)$ /get_app.php?username=$1 [L]`

And in your get_app.php Script you have the "username" parameter available in the request to do sth. with it.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you so much! I'll have to read some more on the .htaccess file!

Comment: Is there a way to redirect to the new URL as well? Now it is showing the correct page but the URL is still the /user/username one. I think it would look better if the /get_app.php was visible in the url

Comment: Then you have to add **[R=301,L]** instead of the **[L]** at the end, should work